# assignment expressions with conditional expression

Tags: python, python-3.8, python-assignment-expression

The following snippet

```
def expensive_function(x):
    return x

x = 10.5
(int(y) if y.is_integer() else y := expensive_function(x))
```

raises

```
SyntaxError: cannot use assignment expressions with conditional expression
```

Can assignment expressions not be used in this way?

If not, what is wrong with my assumption: I was under the impression the idea is to pre-assign a dummy value to an expensive operation in a single expression.

---

To clarify the idea is asking if assignment operations can be used to simplify by assigning `expensive_function(x)` to a dummy variable

```
def expensive_function(x):
    return x

x = 10.5
(int(expensive_function(x))
 if expensive_function(x).is_integer()
 else expensive_function(x))
```

Comment: Could you not just do `int(y) if y.is_integer() else expensive_function(x)`?

Comment: this is a minimal example - the code structure can be changed but I am focusing on the usage of the assignment operator explicitly with conditional expressions

Comment: the error is the reproducible part ..

Comment: In your minimal sample, the role of `y` is not clear. When are you assigning value to `y`, before invoking its `is_integer()` method?

Comment: that's the issue - I wasn't aware that the statement was assigned in order from left to right. I thought that assignments were made up-front

Comment: Your edit made the question even more confusing, I'd assumed that `y` was a different variable predefined other than `x`, now its unclear what you're trying to save yourself from doing

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mre] with all variable defined.

Comment: See my answer Alex, I have answered your question.

Comment: edited @martineau to contain reproducible example

Comment: @keepAlive - sorry will check in 20mins as on a call

Comment: Alexander: While the snippet reproduces the error, `y` is undefined, which makes working on a solution more difficult. It appears to be the name of a `float` value, but I shouldn't need to guess. Being imprecise like that is likely at least part of the reason why there have been so many answers to your questio — and it wastes everyone's time.

Comment: thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
z = int(y) if (y := expensive_function(x)).is_integer() else y
```

?

---

Actually, in `a if cond else b`, there are two conditional expressions: the `a`- and the `b`-members. But the middle member, i.e. the `cond` one is not conditional: it is *always evaluated*, explaining why using an assigment operator there raises no error.

---

A prior-to-3.8 approach (i.e. with no [Walrus Operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions)) can be

```
z = (
    lambda y: int(y) if y.is_integer() else y
)(
    expensive_function(x)
)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of "Can assignment expressions not be used in this way?"

Comment: @Sayse does it answer the question now ? :)

Comment: that seems exactly what I'm asking for... I will check

Comment: @keepAlive - I still don't understand what the question is exactly

Comment: Thanks, this addresses both the issue of the assignment not being evaluated up-front as well as showing how to use assignments to avoid expensive function calls in a loop

Answer (score 2):

```py
int(y) if y.is_integer() else y := expensive_function(x)
```

is equivalent to

```py
def foo(x):
  if y.is_integer():
     return int(y)
  else:
     y = expensive_function(x)
     return y
foo(x)
```

Now you can see where the problem is. `y` isn't defined!

Comment: thanks - I previously thought assignment was done first; then the rest of the expression

Comment: great! although I was wondering why you would want to convert to int if it's already an int?!

Comment: perhaps you were looking for `if not y.is_integer()`?

Comment: Maybe because `is_integer` does the same kind of job as `isdigit`, which checks implicite types of strings, e.g. `int('2') if '2'.isdigit() else '2'`.

Comment: @keepAlive oh yeah, that could be!

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane would be great, if you can upvote / accept one our answers. If none of the answers are helpful, kindly tell us what exactly you're looking for

Comment: both are answer two parts of the question tbh - sorry I had to run into meetings. Yours pointed out that misnomer that the assignment wasn't evaluated upfront, whereas https://stackoverflow.com/a/64391064/4013571 shows how to correctly assign it - as a result I upvoted them both, many thanks for your help